# VS community 2015 Update 3 has no Master configuration

Tags: uwp-xaml

Using Unity 5.5.2f1 and Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3, making a UWP game. Unity makes an app package and correctly runs the app. VS configuration is set to Release, as there is only Debug and Release.
The Store rejects the .appx file as not being a valid store app.

There used to be a Master configuration in older VS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it seems you are exporting your project from Unity to UWP. If so, you can try with the following steps.

> 1. When you are ready to export your project from Unity, open the **File** menu and select **Build Settings...**
> 2. Click **Add Open Scenes** to add your scene to the build
> 3. In the Build Settings dialog, choose the following options to export for UWP:
>
>    - **Platform**: ***Windows Store*** and be sure to select **Switch Platform** for your selection to take effect
>    - **SDK**: ***Universal 10***
>    - **UWP Build Type**: ***D3D or XAML***
> 4. **Optional**: **Unity C# Projects**: Checked. NOTE: Checking this box allows you to 1.) debug your app in the Visual Studio remote debugger, and 2.) edit scripts in the Unity C# project while using IntelliSense for WinRT APIs.
> 5. From the **Build Settings...** window, open **Player Settings...** and enter your game details
> 6. Return to the **Build Settings** dialog and then select **Build**
> 7. In the Windows Explorer dialog that appears, create a new folder to hold Unity's build output. For example, we name the folder *"App"*.
> 8. Select the newly created folder and click **Select Folder**.
> 9. Once Unity has finished building, a Windows Explorer window will open to the project root directory. Navigate into the newly created folder (*"App"* as in Setp 7).
> 10. Open the generated Visual Studio solution file located inside this folder.

Then in the opened Visual Studio solution, you should be able to find the "Master" configuration. These configurations are generated by Unity, it should not be related to the version of Visual Studio.

For more info, please refer to [Porting guides](https://unity3d.com/partners/microsoft/porting-guides).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you describe is exactly what I have done. The app created runs correctly on my PC. However, the Store will not accept it, saying it is not a windows store app. I have switched to VS 2017 and will wait for Unity 2017 in hopes this issue will be resolved.

Comment: @JerryLive So can you find the "Master" configuration now? For submitting your app to the Store, you can follow the steps from **Associate your app with Windows Store** to **Uploading packages to your submission** in [Porting guides](https://unity3d.com/partners/microsoft/porting-guides). If you still have problems, please ask a new question with [tag:windows-store-apps] tag.   This is the right tag for Store related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I was slow to use the Porting Guides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I was slow to use the Porting Guides. To submit a UWP app to the store, I Must use Unity 5.3.5 and VS 2015 Update 1. This is an issue for me, since I have made mods to the Project with newer versions of Unity, and the older version won't read the project. However, I will work this out... Thanks again.